# I have just updated my Oauth security certificate for my Xero private app and I now get a 'ERROR: 1Curl error: '

Tags: xero-api

My Xero private app has been working well for about 5 years using the provided php wrapper.  After updating the cert today I now get 'ERROR: 1Curl error: ' when I call a put API.

The app was working fine yesterday but today the cert expired and I started receiving 'No certificates have been regestered for the consumer...'.  I created a new cert and registered the .cer file on the Xero web site.  I replaced my cert files (privatekey.pem & publickey.cer) on the web server.  Now I can log (I get a token back from OAuth) in but I get the unhelpful Curl eror message.

Not sure where to go with this, it seems like a code issue, but the app worked fine yesterady.

Comment: You did replace the consumer key and secret in your code, too? Doubt that's the issue as that should prevent the login, just that you mentioned all the other things and not that.

Comment: In the _Config file I went to update the 'consumer_key' but the value had not changed.  The other key 'shared_secret' was not set and the docs in the file say this is only required for 'partner applications'.  Tracing my code, the loging appears to work fine, and a token is returned.  Its on subsequent calls the CURL error appears.

Comment: It seems strange to me that generating and uploading a new certificate has not resulted in a new key/secret pair. I think you are correct that a private application only needs one of those - the API I'm using takes both, even though it only needs one.

Comment: I thought so too.  I have manually forced it to generate a new key pair and tried that, just to rule that out, still get the same error.